# How to convert txt to csv files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to move files in between multiple gen1 Azure data lake storage instances without having to resort to writing an Azure App Function or directly calling the Azure storage SDK.

The situation is that I've got a few text files in data lake 1 called `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`. They're both files with tabs as delimiters. When I try to use the copy activity with `.csv` as extension, the files do get moved over to data lake 2, but stay `.txt` files.

The copy activity source and sink looks as follows:

```
{
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
            "storeSettings": {
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreReadSettings",
                "recursive": true,
                "wildcardFileName": "*.*",
                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
            },
            "formatSettings": {
                "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
            }
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
            "storeSettings": {
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreWriteSettings"
            },
            "formatSettings": {
                "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                "quoteAllText": true,
                "fileExtension": ".csv"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried copying to a blob container as well, but the same issue remains: the files keep their `.txt` extension.

Is it possible to change the file extension after a copy?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but then I noticed that in the copy data sink settings there is an  option to set file extension, which was set to .txt. I changed it to .csv and it solved the issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the end result filename in the sink dataset, if the files are always going to be called the same then you can hardcore it. If not, it might get a bit more complex because you will want to use a GetMetadata to get every filename, then a Foreach to iterate over them and copy each one with a modified name.

Hope this helped!

Comment: As described in the initial question, I've tried hard-coding the filename in the sink dataset to the `.csv` extension, this didn't work. I've also tried the Get Metadata + ForEach + Copy activity combination, which also didn't work. I've also tried this combination with the Lookup activity, which didn't work either. The files do get copied over every time, but their extension stays `.txt`.

Comment: The extension is just a name, it doesnt affect anything for either the blob storage or data factory. If the content is correct, then you just want to do a name change?

Comment: Yes, I'm really only interested in moving the file and changing the name.